# Adding rich textarea editor on a page with the common buttons like bold,italic, alignment etc

Tags: css, vb.net, html

Please help am trying to add a rich text Area to my web page, how can i go about it. 
I have not tried anything yet

Comment: [Look here!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214453/rich-text-editor-replacement-for-html-textarea)

Answer (score 5):

instead all this things just add three lines in html

```
<textarea></textarea>
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>
```

And you will get the textarea as an editable.

If Helpful vote my answer

Answer (score 0):

with normal html ?:)

[Rich text editor replacement for html textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214453/rich-text-editor-replacement-for-html-textarea)

more information what do you want to do will help..

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you can use in your web page, 
try this for javascript page (no jquery)
http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxEditor/

or if you use jquery there are more options available, one of them is
markItUp - http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/